# firebase reauthentication flow with Token in react js app not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, mobx-react

after an hour the user get disconnected from the firebase functions and gets an error.
the connection to firebase in the app work like this:

After the first connection via google, the token is sent to firebase functions.
after that a `getIdToken(ture)` to force a refresh in `useEffect`.
the token is saved in the state via mobX and every time a commend requires to send or get data from the data base it's passes the token to the firebase functions
I have noticed that I don't get a new token in `.then(function (idToken) {...}`
this is the error :

```
FirebaseAuthError: Firebase ID token has expired. 
Get a fresh ID token from your client app and try again (auth/id-token-expired). 
See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.
...
...
...
>    errorInfo: {
>      code: 'auth/id-token-expired',
>      message: 'Firebase ID token has expired. 
Get a fresh ID token from your client app and try again (auth/id-token-expired). 
See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.'
>    },
>    codePrefix: 'auth'
>  }
```

Things that I have tried already:

1. is to separate the  `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then()` to a different `useEffect()`.
2. call `getIdToken()` after I get an error from the firebase functions.

```
const UserSubscriber = () => {
//using mobX here 
  const { user } = useStores();
  const token = user.store.token;
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!token.length || !firebase.auth().currentUser) return;
    firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(function (idToken) {
      const decodedToken = jwt.decode(idToken, '', true);
      if (!decodedToken.user_id) return;
      const unsub = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(decodedToken.user_id).onSnapshot(docSnapshot => {
        const data = docSnapshot.data();
//user.mergeData() is just to store data
        if (!data) return user.mergeData({ noUser: true, token: idToken })
        user.mergeData({ ...data, noUser: false, token: idToken })
      });
      return () => unsub();
    }).catch(function (error) {
      user.logOut();
    });
  }, [token, user]);

  return useObserver(() => (
    <div />
  ));
}
```

and in the backend

```
app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(req.body.token);
    let uid = decodedToken.uid;
    req.uid = uid;
    return next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(401).send();
  }
});
```

I have tried `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(userAuth => {...})` (in side of the `useEffect()`)

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(userAuth => {
      userAuth.getIdToken().then(function (idToken) {
        const decodedToken = jwt.decode(idToken, '', true);
        if (!decodedToken.user_id) return;
        const unsub = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(decodedToken.user_id).onSnapshot(docSnapshot => {
          const data = docSnapshot.data();
          if (!data) return user.mergeData({ noUser: true, token: idToken })
          user.mergeData({ ...data, noUser: false, token: idToken })
        });
        return () => unsub();
      }).catch(function (error) {
        user.logOut();
      });
    })
;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can use onAuthStateChange : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged
and get your id with the result (user.getIdToken())

Comment: I have change it to this 
`firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(userAuth => {
      userAuth.getIdToken().then(function (idToken) {...`
but it haven't change
the same problem as before